# How to get combinations(that start with 'a') of letters from a to z in lexicographical order

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sample output:

["a","b", "c", "d", .., "z", "ab",... "az"..., "abc", "abd",..."abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"]

I have tried the code

```
function generate(st, s) 
    { 
        if (s.length == 0) { 
            return; 
        } 
        if (!st.has(s)) { 
            st.add(s); 
            for (let i = 1; i <= s.length; i++) { 
                let t = s;
                t = t.substring(0, i); 
                console.log(t);
            } 
        } 
        return; 
    } 

let st = new Set();
generate(st, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
```

but do not know how to proceed from here.

Comment: please add the end of the combinations as well.

Comment: *"Traverse current string, one by one // remove every character and recur. "* But ... you don't recurse there...?

Comment: You realize this is going to be a **massive** set, right? :-)

Comment: Yeah, stuck on the same @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 0):

You could take a generator function and return the actual string, if needed and the result of the calls with the actual letter and without.

The result is ordered by occurence of the letters.

```js
function* generate([first, ...rest], temp = '', take) {
    if (take) yield temp;
    if (first === undefined) return;
    
    yield* generate(rest, temp + first, true);
    yield* generate(rest, temp);
}

console.log([...generate('abcde')]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Good one Nina! But in the output to this even the combinations that start with b, c,d,e are returned. However, as per the expected output, we look for only sorted order with 'a' combinations like ["a","b", "c", "d", .., "z", "ab",... "az"..., "abc", "abd",..."abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"]

Answer (score 0):

Get the all the possible combinations from 2nd letter to end (2^n combinations without first letter 'a'). Add the letter `a` to all combinations should get your expected results.

```js
function generate(str) {
  const [first, ...chars] = [...str];
  let list = [first];
  chars.forEach((char) => {
    list = list.concat(list.map(item => `${item}${char}`))
  })
  return list;
}

console.log(generate('abcdefghij'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function generate ([...word], f) {
  let res = [f]
  word.forEach(i=> {
       word.shift()
       word.reduce((a,c) => {
        res.push(f+a+c) 
        return a+c 
       }, '')
  })
  return res 
}

showResult(generate('abcdefghij', 'a'));

// helper function
function showResult(result) {
  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```